# oauth2client is now deprecated

Tags: python, credentials, google-auth-library, requests-oauthlib

In the Python code for requesting data from Google Analytics ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py ) via an API, oauth2client is being used. The code was last time updated in July 2018 and until now the oauth2client is deprecated. My question is can I get the same code, where instead of oauth2client, google-auth or oauthlib is being used ?

I was googling to find a solution how to replace the parts of code where oauth2client is being used. Yet since I am not a developer I didn't succeed. This is how I tried to adapt the code in this link ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py ) to google-auth. Any idea how to fix this ?

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.urllib3 import AuthorizedHttp


SCOPES = ['...']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('...')
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secrets.json' # Path to client_secrets.json file.
VIEW_ID = '...'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes the analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:l
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)


  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
authed_http = AuthorizedHttp(credentials)

response = authed_http.request(
    'GET', SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)

  return analytics

def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body=
    {
    "reportRequests":[
    {
      "viewId":VIEW_ID,
      "dateRanges":[
      {
        "startDate":"2019-01-01",
        "endDate":"yesterday"
      }],
      "dimensions":[
      {
        "name":"ga:transactionId"
      },
      {
        "name":"ga:sourceMedium"
      },
      {
        "name":"ga:date"
      }],
      "metrics":[
      {
        "expression":"ga:transactionRevenue"
      }]
    }]
  }
).execute()


def printResults(response):
  for report in response.get("reports", []):
    columnHeader = report.get("columnHeader", {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get("dimensions", [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get("metricHeader", {}).get("metricHeaderEntries", [])
    rows = report.get("data", {}).get("rows", [])

    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get("dimensions", [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get("metrics", [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print (header + ": " + dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get("values")):
          print (metric.get("name") + ": " + value)


def main():

  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  printResults(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

I need to obtain response in form of a json with given dimensions and metrics from Google Analytics.
```

Answer (score 1):

For those running into this problem and wish to port to the newer auth libraries, do a diff b/w the 2 different versions of the short/simple Google Drive API sample at the [code repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/gsuite-apis-intro) for the [G Suite APIs intro codelab](https://g.co/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro) to see what needs to be updated (and what can stay as-is). The bottom-line is that the API client library code can remain the same while all you do is swap out the auth libraries underneath.

Note that sample is only for *user acct auth*... for *svc acct auth*, the update is similar, but I don't have an example of that yet (working on one though... will update this once it's published).